# Why smale horseshoe satisfies the Axiom A?

Tags: dynamical-systems, stability-theory

I'm studying Shub's book (global stability of dynamical systems), and it wasn't clear to me why the horseshoe satisfies Axiom A, can someone explain why, or even indicate another book that explains it clearly?

Comment: All is easier here at the level of symbolic dynamics.

Comment: Thanks, it really becomes easier to see at the level of symbolic dynamics, since the periodic points are dense in the space of the symbols, and through the conjugation between this and the horseshoe, we conclude that the non-wandering of the horseshoe is equal to the closure of periodic points